# how to create TextFields dynamically in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

we are developing Mobile application in j2me.In my application, we are using TextField and some other controls in Form.Here, my problem is i want to dynamically create TextField based on User's Credentials.For Example, If Manager is entered,then i want to create certain TextField(based on Manager Selection) for getting input from the Manager.Otherwise,i just want to create TextField that are less than the Manager TextField.

How to Create TextFields Dynamically...

For example like this...

```
int userSelection=10;

for(int i=0;i<userSelection;i++)
    TextField text=new TextField("Some Name",null);
```

here, our problem is,

I want to create TextField With Different Name...

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: what API are you using? eg, in midp lcdui [TextField](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html) there's simply no constructor that would allow `new TextField("Some Name",null)`

Comment: Yeah its not available in MIDP 2.0. look my answer. and use like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the TextField array and refer from array index.

```
TextField[] textFields = new TextField[10];
for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
     textFields[0] = new TextField(label, text, maxSize, constraint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after you use correct parameters to construct TextField, code might look like

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import java.util.Vector;
// ...
    Vector newTextFields(int userSelection) {
        // neither List nor generics in midp sorry

        final int MAX_SIZE = 42;
        final Vector list = new Vector();
        for(int i=0; i < userSelection; i++) {
            list.addElement(new TextField("Name #" + i, null,
                    MAX_SIZE, TextField.ANY);
        }
        return list;
    }
// ...
```